# shutdownguest vmware ansible

Tags: ansible, vmware

I am trying to shutdown a guest in ansible using vmware_guest

Nothing I do is working.

Can anyone help?

What is the yml code to just initiate guest shutdown?

Many Thanks

Chris

Comment: I know this post is pretty old, but it will be easier to debug or provide solution if you post what you have already tried. It will help others facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used vmware_guest, but take a look at the documentation on https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/vmware_guest_module.html . It seems pretty easy, something like:

```
- hosts: vmwaremaster
  tasks:
    - name: shutdown myguest
      vmware_guest:
        hostname: ip_of_vcenter
        password: pwassword_of_vcenter
        username: username_of_vcenter
        name: myguest
        state: shutdownguest
```

Comment: maybe you ran into https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/19080 => Try to use a more recent version